# when datetime objects casted to string, language of month name not match with culture info

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I set culture info to turkish, but when datetime object casted to string(""+h.DogumTarihi) it looks like; Jan.26.1989

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");

                EvlilikRaporuVM mdl  = (from r in raporRepo
                                 join h in hastaRepo on r.HastaTc equals h.HastaTc
                                 select new EvlilikRaporuVM
                                 {
                                     ID = Id,
                                     BirthDate =  "" + h.DogumTarihi,
...
```

how to force datetime object to get language info from current culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `CurrentCulture`:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");
```

With this, the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
```

Outputs:

> 25 Eylül 2018 Salı